# Is there any widget framework for Silverlight like Telerik ASP.NET Dock?

Tags: silverlight, widget, dashboard

There are some nice frameworks which allow to make a dashboard with draggable widgets. For example:

http://dropthings.omaralzabir.com/
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dock/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx

They behave like ASP.NET WebParts: there are some zones on page and the user can place widgets into these zones.

Is there any framework which offers the same functionality for Silverlight applications?

Answer (score 0):

Is sounds like you need a tile view.

Infragistics [do one](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/silverlight/xamwebtileview.aspx#Overview) and there will be other control sets that offer this as well, though I couldn't find one in the Telerik controls.

It's also something you could implement yourself - though as with all these things you need to weigh up the cost of the controls vs the time it would take you to develop it.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! TileView may fit my needs. But it looks like all tiles are the same size in the TileView, whereas my widgets are different.

Comment: @Pavel - you could set up several columns to allow different height tiles or several rows to allow different widths.